# Como hacer que una aplicacion HTML5 offline no pida permisos de comunicación que no uso

Tags: javascript, android, html5, ios

Estoy desarrollando aplicaciones HTML5 (sin frameworks) offlines, actualmente para empaquetar uso Intel XDK pero podría pasarme a otro si hiciera falta.
La duda que tengo, es que como son aplicaciones que funcionan desde el navegador, la instalación pide permisos para usar internet/wifi, pero al ser offlines, no hacen falta dichos permisos. ¿Como puedo especificar que no requiero dichos permisos para que no los pida al instalar las apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esta [cadena del foro de Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/html5-application-development/topic/532663?language=ru) (en inglés) se menciona que el permiso de Redes/Internet está activado por defecto en la versión de Cordova usada en Intel XDK, y que no puede deshabilitarse:

> By default, all apps built with Apache Cordova* using Intel XDK has the Network feature enable. Currently, there isn't a method of disabling this.

Aunque el post y la respuesta tienen más de un año y puede que las cosas hayan cambiado. En el IDE puedes añadir permisos (en Cordova Hybrid Mobile App Settings > Building Settings > Android), pero cuando creas un proyecto no se puede quitar el de Internet (porque la lista está vacía).

---

Si usas directamente Cordova, puedes ver los permisos para android en el fichero:

```
ruta_del_proyecto/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Allí encontrarás que cuando creas una nueva aplicación, está esta línea de código:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

que puedes borrar para que la aplicación no pida ni siquiera el permiso de redes e Internet.

Pero no sé cómo de recomendable es eliminar ese permiso. En esta [pregunta de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697295/are-all-those-permissions-needed-by-phonegap-on-android) se menciona que hay varios permisos que son necesarios para que corran las apps con Cordova. Y se dice que el de Internet es requerido (por aquello de ejecutarse en el navegador).

En esa misma pregunta se menciona una alternativa para que no se pida ningún permiso. Añadir esta línea al `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

En la propia [documentación de PhoneGap](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_features.md.html) (mira al final) se menciona esta posibilidad y pone que el permiso de Internet es requerido (aunque es una versión antigua y puede que no esté al día):

```
<!--
  If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
  following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
  permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
-->
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

---

Como curiosidad, probé a crear una aplicación de prueba, borré el permiso de Internet (dejando la aplicación sin ningún permiso) y la app se compiló y ejecutó sin problemas en una tableta (el código por defecto). Puede que la última versión de Cordova no requiera ningún permiso especial.

Estos son los pasos que seguí desde la línea de comandos:

```
cordova create test com.alvaro.test Test

cd test

cordova platform add android

## Aquí edité AndroidManifest.xml ##

cordova build android

cordova run android --device
```

La app corrió sin problemas y si miro en las propiedades (Settings > Apps > Test) veo que no tiene ningún permiso (si añado Internet, veo que tiene "Full network access").

Comment: Lo miraré... pero NO uso cordova, solo HTML5 standard, a no ser que el XDK lo "meta" por defecto... gracias por la información.

Comment: Aunque tu app sea sólo en HTML5, XDK se basa en Cordova para compilar y construir la app (se menciona en la página de [Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-the-cordova-for-android-ios-etc-build-option)), aunque sigue una estructura diferente para ficheros y configuraciones

Comment: Modificando el archivo de configuración para el XDK de la app (nombreDeApp.xdk) incluyendo un "permissions":"none" y un "android-permission":"none" en la sección "Android"->"preferences_"  he conseguido que al empaquetar creara el XML con las opciones:

<preference name="permisions" value="none"/>
<preference name="android-permision" value="none"/>

Pero al instalar la app me sigue pidiendo los permisos de comunicación, supongo que porque no sobrescribe los que incluye automáticamente, de manera que tendría que empaquetar el apk a mano, cosa que pretendía ahorrarme.